# New bash session with a user from the current one

Tags: unix

How can i create a **new bash session** with a user from the **current bash session**,
I know i can do it with only one command
tryin to figure it out.

Comment: wrong site, however you can use `bash --login`, or I think you're looking for `screen` / `tmux`, google them.

Comment: try move this question to [`Unix&Linux`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and elaborate it

Comment: I think i'll just leave it here, thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ su <user> -c bash
```

replace the username desired. You will either need to know the password of the user or run it as root.

or, you could do any of the following

```
$ screen -S <user>
$ bash --login <user>
```

All of which will accomplish your task

Answer (score 1):

Reference Linux screen command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

You can create a new session in your bash by this:

```
screen -S test
```